# Possivel implementar KeyEvent em uma classe que herda de Qwidget em vez de QFrame

Tags: c++, qt

Minha classe:

```
class Jogador : public QWidget {
Q_OBJECT

public:
    Jogador(QWidget* parent = NULL);
    void draw();
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event);
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event);

private:

    int x,y,w,h;
    QVBoxLayout* layout;
};
```

Minha Função:

```
void Jogador::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event) {
    QWidget::keyPressEvent(event);

    switch (event->key()) {
    case Qt::Key_Up:
        x+=20;
        repaint();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

A pergunta é: eu vou conseguir fazer o evento de teclas funcionar em uma classe que herda de `QWidget`, ou somente `QFrame`?

meu main está assim:

```
#include<QApplication> 
   #include<tabuleiro.h>
   #include<jogador.h>
   #include<QWidget>
   int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget window;
    Tabuleiro t(&window);
    Jogador j(&window);
    window.show();



    return app.exec();
    return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Um `QFrame` nada mais é que um `QWidget` que é renderizado com uma borda a mais. Ele não acrescenta nenhuma outra funcionalidade que tenha algo haver com algum evento. Dito isso, tudo que você fizer e funcionar em um `QFrame`, também funcionará em um `QWidget`.

Agora, ao seu código: Em um evento você deve ou lidar com ele, ou repassar para um ancestral que vá lidar. No seu caso você primeiro está pedindo ao seu pai (o  `QWidget`) para lidar com o evento. E na sequencia você mesmo processa ele. Isso não deixa de funcionar, mas não é ideal. Aqui uma versão corrigida:

```
void Jogador::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event) {
    switch (event->key()) {
    case Qt::Key_Up:
        x += 20;
        repaint();
        break;
    default:
        QWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
        break;
    }
}
```

Dito isso, nada mais há de errado com como você implementou. Funciona.

Comment: Dá olhada no meu main, acho que deve ter algo errado. pois não consigo fazer chamar o KeyEvent